# Using ko.utils.arrayForEach to iterate over a observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to calculate sum of 'price' field of an 'observableArray'. I have the following code so far:

```
(function(){

function objFeatures(name,price) {
        return {
            name: ko.observable(name),
            price: ko.observable(price),

            removeFeatures: function () {
                appViewModel.features.remove(this);
            }
        }
    }

var appViewModel = {
features: ko.observableArray([
            new objFeatures("Feature1", 20),
            new objFeatures("Feature2", 20)
        ]),

 grandTotal: ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.features(), function () {
                total += this.price();
            })
            return total;
        })
};

ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);

}());
```

When I try to run this, i get an **"Error: this.features is not a function"** in the firebug console.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I know this is an ask given it was 8 years ago, but in order to understand the accepted answer better, can someone tell me on what line the error would have occurred?

Comment: You are in luck!
@ScottAnderson it occured on this line
`ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.features(), function () {`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Computed observables are evaluated immediately during creation.  In your case, `appViewModel` has not been created yet and `this` will not represent the `appViewModel`.

There are many ways to ensure that `this` is correct in this case.  Here are two:

1. Create it outside of your initial object literal:

   ```
   var appViewModel = {
      features: ko.observableArray([
          new objFeatures("Feature1", 20),
          new objFeatures("Feature2", 20)
          ])
   };

   appViewModel.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.features(), function(feature) {
           total += feature.price();
       });

       return total;
   }, appViewModel);
   ```
2. Create your view model in a function:

   ```
   var AppViewModel = function() {
       this.features = ko.observableArray([
           new objFeatures("Feature1", 20),
           new objFeatures("Feature2", 20)
       ]);

       this.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
           var total = 0;
           ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.features(), function(feature) {
               total += feature.price();
           });
           return total;
       }, this);
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());​
   ```

Comment: i went with the first approach, now i cant access `this.price()`

Comment: Finally i used (I have absolutely no idea how this worked)--- `var self = this;
            $.each(self.features(), function () {
                total += this.price();
            });`  but using ko.utils.arrayForEach still does not work, thank you for your response though.

Comment: @Nthapa13 I did not notice the syntax that you were using on that part.  I updated the answers above to show that the function that you specify in `ko.utils.arrayForEach` receives the item as its first argument, then you do not need to use `this` in the function.