# Set observable value for all objects in viewmodel observablearray?

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

So I have a kind of complex viewmodel that someone else built, and I have created a new property called "selected".  This is for a UI indicator, obviously.  I have successfully bound the click function  to call "this.selected(true)" but my question is, how can I set all others to false?  Is there an easy method, something like "all.selected(false)"?  Or will I Have to do a foreach loop of some sort?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ko.utils.arrayForEach to iterate over a observableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351939/using-ko-utils-arrayforeach-to-iterate-over-a-observablearray)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.  Found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351939/using-ko-utils-arrayforeach-to-iterate-over-a-observablearray).

```
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.entities(), function (entity) {
        entity.selected(false);
    });
```